# Can last observation carried forward (LOCF) be used in a meta analysis?

Tags: missing-data, meta-analysis

In an article I am reviewing, the authors used LOCF for missing data.  In ordinary studies, I would frown on this and suggest multiple imputation. However, this study was a meta-analysis.

Is LOCF an appropriate method for missing data in a meta-analysis?

Comment: Since it is not a valid method to use in individual studies I don't see how it can be valid in a meta analysis of multiple studies.  Besides being biased it doesn't come close to controlling type I error because of gross underestimation of standard errors.

Comment: Thanks Frank.   That was my impression but I wanted to get either other views or confirmation of mine before making recommendations.

Comment: I am not quite clear on the question: Are you meta-analyzing reported results of individual studies that used LOCF? In that case it might be better to use these studies than to discard them despite their methodological shortcomings, but clearly the meta-analysis would inherit any limitations the original studies being meta-analyzed have. Or is the LOCF somehow being done in the meta-analysis itself? If so, I do not understand from your question why/how/in what way.

Comment: The authors just said that missing data was dealt with by using LOCF.  It wasn't entirely clear in the article itself.

Comment: My hope is that the authors are not using baseline data and LOCF to impute the post-treatment effect estimates. I see this as baseless with only a few rare exceptions. Even then, I would strongly question the methodological soundness. Now having said that, if they are using data from trials that used LOCF then there are several options based on their statistical competence including accounting for the uncertainty caused by LOCF (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25492741), excluding these trial data or including and conducting a sensitivity analysis. In general, I favor the last approach.